# How to write just one 0x0A character to STDOUT in Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows

How to write just one 0x0A character to STDOUT in Ruby on Windows. Just one, without 0x0D.

@EDIT: Thanks to all! I knew about binary/text mode concept but have no idea how to deal with this in Ruby interpreter. The solution is to use `STDOUT.binmode`.

There is an open question how than switch STDOUT back to text mode using  platform independent code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the "virtual newline". At the *(Ruby) IO layer* this feature is responsible for mapping "\n" (0x0A, LF) to/from the [Operating Systems definition of a newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Windows maps "\n" to CR+LF (whereas "\n" is mapped unchanged to LF in Unix-like systems).

Use [ios.binmode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000945) to put the stream into binary mode which disables the "virtual newline" mode. This is also very important to do for dealing with binary streams such as images ;-)

Happy coding.

Comment: is there any way to switch STDOUT back to text mode after that? just curious

Comment: @ZAB: From the fine manual (which pst linked to): "Once a stream is in binary mode, it cannot be reset to nonbinary mode."

Comment: @ZAB While it's not possible to reset binmode, it should be possible to open a *new* IO object (to the same underlying fd) in nonbinary mode. I have not tried, however. I am not sure if `IO.reopen` carries the `binmode` flag, but that might be something else to try.

Comment: @user166390, THANK YOU!!! I've never knew what's the difference between text and binary modes, had no idea why piped binary output from the ruby script was broken. Saved my night!